# eclipse ide juno error , see the log file c:\"path to eclipse"\configuration\1394184892937.log

Tags: eclipse

c:\"path to eclipse"\configuration\1394184892937.log
I don't have workspace yet.so there is no .snap file.the error occur when i open eclipse juno.
that happend right after i have updated eclipse.
I even tried reinstalling eclipse.Please help?

here is the some of the log file:
 eclipse.buildId=v21.1.0-569685 java.version=1.6.0_37 java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=ar_SA Framework arguments: -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.pr oduct Command-line arguments: -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.pr oduct

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-03-07 13:15:58.593 !MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved: !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-03-07 13:15:58.593 !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core_3.3.500.v2012 0522-1651.jar was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core 2 0 2014-03-07 13:15:58.593 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.5.100,4.0. 0). !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core 2 0 2014-03-07 13:15:58.593 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.ant_1.6.5. !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-03-07 13:15:58.593 !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.cxx_1.1.0.2 01302132326.jar was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.cxx 2 0 2014-03-07 13:15:58.593 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.filesystem_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2

Comment: And what is in the log file it is telling you to look at?

Comment: it is too long and I don't understand it cause i am a biggener.but here is some of it: